# Xamarin.Forms.WeakEventManager .ctor() is Inaccessible from Xamarin.CommunityToolkit

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am getting the following error when I try to call the expander control in Xamarin forms:

> Xamarin.Forms.WeakEventManager..ctor()' is inaccessible from method Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Expander..ctor()''

I have installed the Xamarin Community Toolkit nuget package and I'm referencing the namespace in my XAML file.

Control wise, I don't think I'm doing anything too crazy - does anybody know how I resolve this error?

My code is as follows:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:Services="clr-namespace:My_App.Services"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:My_App.ViewModels"
             x:Class="My_App.Views.MyPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ContentPageTemplate}"
             >
.
.
.

<xct:Expander HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          Margin="{StaticResource UniversalMargin}" 
          BackgroundColor="Gray">

            <xct:Expander.Header>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="{StaticResource UniversalMargin}">

                    <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        Text="{Binding Name, Converter={Services:NullToUnnamedDeviceConverter}}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" />

                    <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        Text="{Binding BondState, Converter={Services:BondedStateToStringConverter}}" FontSize="Medium"  TextColor="{StaticResource DarkBorder}" />

                </StackLayout>
            </xct:Expander.Header>

            <xct:Expander.Content>
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0" 
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                           Text="Info text goes here" 
                           TextColor="White" 
                           FontSize="Medium"/>

                </Grid>
            </xct:Expander.Content>
</xct:Expander>
```

Comment: Also, I've tried deleting the obj and bin files, cleaning and recompiling, but that hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: I tested the xaml without the Converter and StaticResource . It works well. Check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/WmzM5o4 Check the code which you do not provided.

Comment: Thanks Wendy - Good to know the code works, but I am still getting the error.
The other code seems irrelevant to this since it is just calling other standard controls.

I should also say that the error only happens at runtime - the code compiles successfully.

Comment: I could not reproduce. I run it at Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012. Try to restart the VS and PC to try again. But i still guess it caused by the code.

Comment: I updated my version of Xamarin forms from version 4.8 to 5.0 and this seems to have resolved the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Update Xamarin forms from version 4.8 to 5.0 could solve this issue.